# SQL Server Filtering by DateTime column, when TIME portion is provided sometimes

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2005, where-clause

In an SSRS report, the user searches based on start date and end date.

The challenge is, as I discovered recently, he sometimes, not always, provides the time component while searching.

Currently, the filter is done like this:

```
if @pEndDate is null  
  SET @pEndDate = getdate()  
SET @PEndDate = DateAdd(dd,1,@PEndDate) 

SELECT ........
FROM .....
WHERE ( Createdon >= @PStartDate AND Createdon < @PEndDate)
```

This is fine when he searches without time (example - @PStartDate = 2/23/2015 and @PEndDate = 2/24/2015)

How should I structure the query to deal with the time portion **when** he provides it? (example - @PStartDate = 2/23/2015 15:00 and @PEndDate = 2/24/2015 15:00)

If this is answered elsewhere, please point me to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to match the date part then there are lot options.

1) You can use the `Date` type for the parameter `PEndDate` and `PStartDate` to nullify the time part

2) You can use the `Convert` method to get only date part of the parameter while matching.`CONVERT (DATE, @PEndDate)` OR `CONVERT(varchar,@PEndDate,103)`

3) Get Date Part only from DateTime using DateTime functions
`ATEADD(dd, 0, 
        DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @PEndDate))`

4) Get Date Part only from `DateTime` using `FLOOR` and `CAST` functions

```
CAST( -- Convert the integer to DATE
 FLOOR(-- Get largest Integer less than or equal to the decimal value
   CAST(GETDATE() AS DECIMAL(12, 5)) -- Convert DATETIME to DECIMAL)   
   AS DATETIME) 'Date Part Only'
```

5) Get Date Part only from DateTime using DATEPART and CONVERT functions

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(4),DATEPART(YEAR, @GETDATE)) 
       + '/'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MONTH, @GETDATE)) 
       + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),DATEPART(DAY, @GETDATE)) 
         'Date Part Only'
```

Use whichever method suits you and you find fancy.

---

**UPDATE**

As you mentioned you need to get the time part to `00:00` with date so you can try as,

```
SELECT CAST( convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),112) AS DATETIME)
--This will give you 2015-02-27 00:00:00.000
SELECT DATEADD(ms,-3, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE())+1,0))
--This will give you end of days time 2015-02-27 23:59:59.997
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar,getdate(),103) + ' 12:59:59 PM'
--This will give you custom time 27/02/2015 12:59:59 PM
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to include the time portion in filtering, when he provides it. When he does not provide the time portion, I want to use date1 00:00:00 and date2 12:59:59